# Fill Grafana Dashboard Variable From LoqQL

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, logql

I have a Grafana dashboard and I'd like to define a variable for this dashboard. I'd like the values of this variable will come from LogQL query. To be more specific - in each log I have a field called "site_ids", and I want the values of the variable to be all the different "site_ids" (longs).
So I wrote this query:

```
{_namespace_="namespace",_schema_="schema"}  | logfmt | line_format "{{.site_ids}}"
```

Which seems to work when I just run it in the query executor, this is the output (the actual site_ids):

```
0
-1
196
2
3
...
```

But when putting it as a query when I try to configure a new variable, I see nothing in the `Preview of values`:

[image: Grafana screenshot]

Unfortunately I can barely find documentation about this..

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `label_values` like [this Query Variable section](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/loki/#query-variable)